# SQLAlchemy - Find Items Where a Relation Contains At Least One Element from a List

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a `Product` class and a `Tag` class which have a many-to-many relationship.

`Product.tags` gives me the list of all tags for a product.

I have a list of tags as search criteria: `['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']`.

How can I get a list of products containing at least one tag matching the list?

I can solve this easily using SQL, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it using the ORM way.

`matching_products = Product.query.join(Product.tags).filter( ??? ).all()`

Comment: `tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']`; `Product.query.join(Product.tags).filter(Product.tags.in_(tags)).all()`?

Comment: Error: `in_() not yet supported for relationships.  For a simple many-to-one, use in_() against the set of foreign key values.`